# Prophet Forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, prophet

My dataframe is in weekly level as below:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIWmQ.png)

was trying to implement prophet model using the below code.

```
df.columns = ['ds', 'y']
# define the model
model = Prophet(seasonality_mode='multiplicative')
# fit the model
model1=model.fit(df)

model1.predict(10)
```

I need to predict the output in a weekly level for the next 10 weeks.How can I fix this?

I need to predict the output in a weekly level for the next 10 weeks.How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your dataframe weekly? Please share a sample of the dataframe.

Comment: yes..it is..can you help me?

Comment: I've added an answer. May you check it?

Comment: I was about to edit my answer but you deleted your other question, do you still need the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `model.make_future_dataframe` to create new dates:

```
model = Prophet()
model.fit(df)

future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=10, freq='W')

predictions = model.predict(future)
```

`predictions` will give predicted values for the whole dataframe, you can reach to the forecasted values for the next 10 weeks with simple indexing:

```
future_preds = predictions.iloc[-10:]
```

Comment: Can I ask you something? Periods=10 means? Next 10 week?

Comment: Sorry, there was a little mistake. You also need to state  `freq` inside `make_future_dataframe` since `Prophet` assumes the dataframe has daily frequency by default. `Periods` stand for the number of rows by which a dataframe is extended. So when you set `periods=10, freq='W'` it adds 10 more rows with weekly frequency